# Can I have two regulator for wall fan - one default one and second I externally connect at switch board

Tags: fan

I have bought one wall fan with following specification:

- Fan speed: 1900 RPM
- Voltage: 220-240 V
- Frequency: 50 Hz
- Power: 125 W

It has inbuilt step type regulator with 3 stage button to either slower or faster the fan speed viz., 1=slow, 2=Medium, 3= Highest. As shown in the image below. Now the problem is that it runs fast at the very 1st stage (i.e 1=slow) and I want it to further slow down.

[image]

Hence I bought one another step type electronic regulator as shown with red rectangle in the image below and I am going the connect it in the switching board as is with the ceiling fan. But I have doubt that whether two regulator will work with that fan or not. Can any body help in choosing the best solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance !

[image: Multi step electronic regulator]

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is about the use of electric devices.

Comment: this question seems to fall in the gap between here and home-improvement.

Comment: @user3099630 I'd be looking for a fan with a remote control. trying to hook to regulators to a fan isn't going to work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the most common products, the added regulator work by reducing the supply voltage while the built-in regulator works by changing the capacitor value or connection point to the motor winding. The two can work together, but attempting to make the slowest speed very much slower may not work very well. The fan speed may vary and it may be difficult to adjust the fan to a slow speed without having is stop completely. It will probably work best if the fan regulator is set to the fastest speed and the added regulator is used only to reduce the speed from that point.

Comment: Thank you @Charles Cowie ! for spreading light to the issue. I wanted generic answer as you described above. It definitely helped me.